# Firebase Anonymous User once upgraded

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm implementing a workflow where every user using my app is an anonymous user until they sign-in/up (either email or Google).

To sign **up**, it's straightforward: I use `linkWithPopup`.

However, I had some issues with user signing **in**: I try to link them and, if I get the `auth/credential-already-in-use` error (happens if the user upgrades once, signs out and then try to sign in again), I sign them in.

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.linkWithPopup(provider).then(function (result) {
        var token = result.credential.accessToken;
        // The signed-in user info.
        var user = result.user;
        // ...
    }).catch(function (error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        if (errorCode === 'auth/credential-already-in-use') {
            return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(error.credential);
        }
    }).then((result) => {
        return dispatch(loadContent(result.user.uid))
    }).then(() => {
        history.push('/');
    });
```

The code above is working great and that's less hassle than doing it all by myself.

However, how do I remove the anonymous users which are created and orphan in case the user signs **in**?

I tried to make a reference to the old useless anonymous user and to delete it once the user is signed **in** (and so, changed its account) but it is obviously not working because the account changed and that would be a big security flaw if a user could delete another one...

I'm not very familiar with Firebase ecosystem, how should I handle that? Do I need to use a combination of `Firebase Cloud Function` and `Firebase Admin SDK` or is there a standard way of solving this problem?

Comment: I don't think there's any "standard" here.  You can certainly use the admin SDK any way you like to delete that account.  You're not obliged to use Cloud Functions, but you can, if you find it helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite simple. APIs on the user continue to work even if the user is not current.

```
const anonymousUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
firebase.auth().currentUser.linkWithPopup(provider)
  .then(function (result) {
    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
    // The signed-in user info.
    var user = result.user;
    // ...
  }).catch(function (error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    if (errorCode === 'auth/credential-already-in-use') {
        return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(error.credential);
    }
  }).then((result) => {
    if (anonymousUser.uid !== result.user.uid) {
      return anonymousUser.delete()
        .then(() => {
          return result;
        });
    }
    return result;
  }).then((result) => {
    return dispatch(loadContent(result.user.uid))
  }).then(() => {
    history.push('/');
  });
```